# How to extract TrueType Fonts (TTF) from Collections (TTC) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, truetype, fontforge

What I'd like to do is to take a TTC file, extract all the included TTFs from it and save them to the documents directory of my app. Does anybody have an idea how to do so? Is there a library which would help?

I have found OS X solutions like fondu or Font Forge but haven't been able to make them run under iOS.

Comment: So you want your app to load the `.ttc` and extract `.ttf` files from it?  I doubt your app even has access to the `.ttc` files... have you tried?

Comment: Well actually you can load them into the documents directory of the app from where you can access them. Let's assume they are there and I want to extract the TTFs from them.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [pyftsubset](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can be installed with `pip3 install fonttools`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Install required python dependencies with
# pip3 install fonttools

font="${1}"

for n in {0..10} ; do
    pyftsubset --font-number=${n} \
            --output-file="${font%.*}_${n}.ttf" \
            --verbose
done
```

`pyftsubset` also lets you cherry-pick specific Unicode ranges, and skip the glyphs that you do not want to include. This can be used with both TTC and TTF files, so you can for example reduce the font size by removing everything you don't need from fonts such as e.g. Arial Unicode.
For example the following script will only include Chinese, Latin and Bopomofo Unicode ranges:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Install required python dependencies with
# pip3 install fonttools

font="${1}"

for n in {0..10} ; do
    echo $n  #             CHINESE               BASIC LATIN               BOPOMOFO
    pyftsubset "${font}" --unicodes=U+4E00-9FFF --unicodes=U+0000-007F --unicodes=U+3100-312F \
            --font-number=${n} \
            --output-file="${font%.*}_chinese_only_${n}.ttf" \
            --verbose
done
```

*NOTE*: The script will iterate the font index from 0 to 10 — most ttc collections will have less files than 10 that so the script will show errors with the last few indexes that don't exist.